# Back to root viewController from UISearchController Cancel-Button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have a simple app which contains a `UISearchController` within a tableView (bottom view in the screenshot).

[image]

The initial segue works fine, the `UISearchController` becomes visible after the barButton (lupe-icon) was hit.

But now I want to hide that SearchTableView when the user hits the Cancel-Button of the searchController (the app should return to the initial viewController). I tried the following

```
func didDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    // cancel?
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

... but nothing happens. So how can I return to the root viewController from this point?

Answer (score 0):

Try to dismiss the search bar first:

```
func didDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.active = false
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: Seems that this makes no difference in my case. It's still doing nothing notable.

Comment: Have you set the delegates for the UISearchController? Try to put a breakpoint inside this function to be sure that the code is processed.

Comment: Yes, I set the UISearchController `self.resultSearchController.delegate = self` in viewWillAppear.